# How to change the session timeout in Jahia?

Tags: jahia

I need to change the session timeout in a Jahia application. Which property/file should I change to achieve that? Also will that be valid for edit mode also?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session timeout can be changed in the file `jahia_installation/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`

The following configuration has to be set:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

For the users in the edit mode, the session timeout can be set in jahia.properties file under `jahia_installation/digital-factory-config/jahia/jahia.properties`

```
# This property sets the session lifetime (minutes)
sessionExpiryTime = 60
```